# How to prove a sampling algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, random

This is a homework question. In order to print M sorted distinct random integers in range [0,N) we can use the following algorithm:

`int n = N 
int m = M 
for i in [0,N)
    if (bigrandom() % n--) < m) 
        print i
        m--`

As we know, this algorithm pick all integers in the range with equal probability. Could you help me to prove it ?

Comment: Would saying "This is Knuth, TAOCP, section 3.4.2" be too *much* help or too *little* help?

Answer (score 1):

1. The chance of having any particular number selected is `m/n`.
2. If this number is selected, we have same problem, but with `n' = n - 1` and `m' = m - 1`. If it's not, we have same problem, but with `n' = n - 1` and `m' = m`.

Your algorithm is an implementation of this idea.

You'll also need to prove assumption `1`, but that you can probably do yourself.